# JSON данные обработка на Jquery и вывод в HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, vkontakte-api

Проблема в том, что не получается из функции, которая принимает данные, взять и обработать данные пользователей.
 Прошу помочь и подробно рассказать, как это сделать, ибо перечитал гайды, но нечего не помогло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
function sendRequest(method, params, func) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.vk.com/method/friends.search?count=60&fields=photo_100&access_token=----&v=5.72',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSONP',
            success: function(data) {console.log(data);}
            // Получение ответа и вывод в консоле (подразумевается что data это название или обозначение JSON массива
    });
    }

    function loadFriends() {
        sendRequest('friends.search', {count: 60, fields: 'photo_100'}, function (data) {
            drawFriends(data);
        });

    }

    function drawFriends(data) {
    // В этом случае JSON файл не дублируется в консоли, не выводит нечего в HTML.
        var html = '';

        var f = friends[i];
        html += +'<h4>' + f.first_name + '</h4>';

        var bdjson = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(bdjson);
        alert (response.item[1]);
        html += +'<h4>' + bdjson.item[1].first_name + '</h4>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так.

```js
// Defined to be called from ajax
$.fn.drawFriends = function (data) {
  // В этом случае JSON файл не дублируется в консоли, не выводит нечего в HTML.
  var html = "";
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  //         Этот массив неизвестен ???
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  var friends = [{first_name: "Petrov"}];
  var i = 0;
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  
  var f = friends[i]; // Is not defined !!!!
  html += '<h1>' + f.first_name + '</h1>';

  var bdjson = data;//$.parseJSON(data); // В случае с получением JSON не нужно парсить 
  console.log(data[0]); // debug print

  html += '<h3>' + bdjson[0].name + '</h3><br>'; // first_name changed to name
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  
  var res = document.getElementById("res");
  res.innerHTML += html;
  //----------------------------------------------------------------
  
}

function sendRequest(method, params, func) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', // testing JSON
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    success: function(data) {
      $.fn.drawFriends(data); // Обработка результатов
    }
    // Получение ответа и вывод в консоле (подразумевается что data это название или обозначение JSON массива
  });
}

function loadFriends() {
  sendRequest('friends.search', {
    count: 60,
    fields: 'photo_100'
  }, function(data) {
    drawFriends(data);
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="sendRequest()">Send</button>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы передаете callback 'func' в sendRequest, но нигде его не вызываете.
Вместо:

```
success: function(data) {console.log(data);}
```

Должно быть:

```
 success: function(data) {func(data);}
```

Или же:

```
success: func
```

У вас же на success просто вызывается функция с console.log